# XQuartz plots not in colour using R on mac

Tags: r, xquartz

I'm very new to R so please forgive any lack of knowledge. I am doing a course which needed the package rgl and managed to work out (finally) that I needed to install XQuartz - which I have done. It is working but I can't get the plots to show in colour - they are only in black and white. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong / how to fix it? I've tried looking at the XQuartz documentation but can't work it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a reproducible example, including your code. I am having no difficulty getting color on my XQuartz device:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- runif(10)
y <- runif(10)
plot(x, y, pch=21, bg=2:6, cex=3)
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Sorry - I'm having real problems with formatting the code block :o/ - steep learning curve. 
library(rgl)
plot3d(x = mtcars$wt,
       y = mtcars$qsec,
       z = mtcars$mpg,
       type = 's', 
       colour = 'green',
       xlim = c(min(mtcars$wt)-1, max(mtcars$wt)+1),
       ylim = c(min(mtcars$qsec)-1, max(mtcars$qsec)+1),
       zlim = c(min(mtcars$mpg)-1, max(mtcars$mpg)+1),
       xlab = 'Weight', 
       ylab = 'Qsec', 
       zlab = 'MPG')

Comment: Sorry - I couldn't work out how to format the code as a code block. Very new to all of this

Comment: Change `colour="green` to `col="green`. Always check the manual page `?plot3d` when you are having problems to make sure you have the arguments specified correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much!